# Sum amount group by id in temporary table

Tags: sql, temp-tables

This is my code:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by date) as rowNo, id, amount
INTO #temptbl
FROM sales
WHERE code = 1000
```

I'm trying to group this temporary table and sum the amount by its id so the id will be unique.

*The row column is mandatory because it will be used later.

I've tried few ways like this,

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by date) as rowNo, id, amount
INTO #temptbl
FROM sales
WHERE code = 1000
GROUP BY id
```

and even tried subquey nad nesting but it wont work. I know the solution must be simple its just i cant see it yet. Thank you

Comment: Any reason you can't use an auto increment column?

Comment: i want it order by date. i also open to any type of solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` with `Partition BY` like this:

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by date) as rowNo, id, 
Sum(amount) over (partition by id) sumAmount
FROM sales
WHERE code = 1000
```

As you know, since you want the Row number then sum amount will be repeated for same ids